# Can't build driver from source. Missing Driver.tmh

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, driver

I'm new to driver development and attempted to integrate the IddSampleDriver from repo https://github.com/ge9/IddSampleDriver into my Windows display management research project. While trying to build the project in Visual Studio, I encountered a roadblock – the absence of the critical "Driver.tmh" file. This file is essential for trace message generation, and its nonexistence led to compilation errors, preventing me from making a straightforward modification to the driver code. The first change I wanted to implement was a simple adjustment to the hardcoded path for the options.txt file.

As a newcomer to driver development, I expected the "Driver.tmh" file to be automatically generated during the Visual Studio build process. This would enable me to proceed with my intended modification of the virtual display driver for my research project. I am seeking concise guidance on configuring Visual Studio to address this issue.

Comment: It builds fine for me. In the project properties pages, under "Wpp Tracing -> General" is "Run Wpp Tracing" set to "Yes"?

Comment: I've re-cloned the repository, and miraculously, the "Driver.tmh" error has disappeared, which is a positive development. However, a new error has surfaced that I'm unfamiliar with: "No file digest algorithm specified. Please specify the digest algorithm with the /fd flag. Using /fd SHA256 is recommended and more secure than SHA1. Calling signtool with /fd sha1 is equivalent to the previous behavior. In order to select the hash algorithm used in the signing certificate's signature, use the /fd certHash option."

I want to emphasize that I'm a novice and my understanding is limited.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the Windows 11 SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/723140/signtool-sign-di-does-not-work-in-windows-11-sdk